# Import External Database Data into Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, dataextensions, import, marketingcloudapi

Hello Salesforce Stack Exchange Members,

Is there a way to setup an integration from an external database (custom built CRM database built in FileMaker Pro) to import data into a Marketing Cloud Data Extension, or wherever it needs to go in order to eventually have it added to a data extension?

My goal is to setup a workflow in our CRM that when a record's status changes, it will send off an HTTP POST request to a node.js system we have with a payload of the customer data (email, first name, last name, contact information, basic details) and have the node.js middleman app then post that data to Marketing Cloud either directly into a Data Extension or somehow get it into Marketing Cloud so that we can trigger an email to send such as a welcome email or transactional email of some sort.

Is this possible to do? According to a trailhead unit I completed ([Import Subscriber Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/email-creation-and-sending/import-subscriber-data?trail_id=create-and-send-targeted-emails-with-email-studio#importing-data-into-a-data-extension)), there are three main ways to import data into a Data Extension, which are:

1. Manually with the Import Wizard
2. Using an Import Activity
3. API using an API call to import your data

The 3rd option seems to be what I'm looking for, but the trailhead module only covers importing the data using the Import Wizard method, which requires creating a CSV or other delimited data file to import which seems to be a pretty manual process.

To summarize, our goal is to be able to import data on the fly using an API call to have the data go from our main customer database in FileMaker Pro to our Marketing Cloud Data Extension which will be used to send emails and SMS messages to our clients such as a welcome email when they sign up with us, and transactional emails like when they reach a certain status in our sales process to give them information they need to know at that point in the process.

Thank you,
Dan.

Comment: Have you looked at the transactional messaging API? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm

Comment: There's the SOAP API's DataExtensionObject or the REST /hub/v1/dataevents endpoint that you can use to insert/upsert Data Extension records. See the developer centre for more information on Marketing Cloud's APIs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm. Journey Builder and the various messaging APIs can be used for sending messages immediately.

Comment: Hi Daniel. This is a very broad question, where you basically ask for a solution design on your integration. I think there remains some work on your side, to investigate in more details, how the different APIs work together, and their limitations (e.g. it is not possible to trigger any event on adding a new record to a data extension).